# Unable to search for files unless complete file name is entered

Tags: google-drive, search

As a company, we store a large amount of product images on Google Drive.
To illustrate the point: we have one product with multiple images (eg. from different angles) all saved with different suffixes e.g. 123456C.jpg, 123456Ca.jpg, 123456Cb.jpg etc.

Working from different browsers on both mac and PC, non of us can search for any file unless we type in the full file name. This makes workflow tricky when usually we'd type in the first 3 numbers or so and up would pop (in the dropdown) all related images.

The small dropdown arrow next to the blue search button with search parameters is set to all file types, unspecified and owned by anyone.

The design studio we work with and have images shared with does not have the same problem. They could start typing in 123... and all the files that start with 123 would pop up to select (below the search bar).

To confuse things further, if we type title: "123" and enter, this works. But it's a workaround, not a solution.Can anyone help?

EDIT: No duplicate qn. - I want to search with the beginning of a filename, not the middle. It seems to work with one account that has shared images with us, but not ours. I believe the problem lies in sharing and ownership but can't work out where.

Comment: Who owns the files? How the files are shared? Are the shared files with you moved to your "My Drive"?

Comment: @AlE the "possible duplicate" that you suggests is clearly specifying that the files to be found are owned by the OP. In this case, instead files owned by user trying to find the files, the employees of one company are trying to find files apparently shared with them.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for getting back to me. The files are in My Drive and 'Shared with Me' They are shared from another google account (the design studio) and they have no problems searching with the beginning of a string. I believe our search should behave in the same way. The folders seem to be owned by the studio, but when you click through, the individual images seem to be owned by me.

Comment: 1) Any clarification should be added to the question itself as comments could be hidden or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that the user who uploaded the images is the owner of them and if you are not finding the images it's more likely that the files were shared with anyone with the link instead of sharing them with specific people including your with your account.

The alternatives are

1. Make the owner of the files share them with your account instead with anyone with the link.
2. Make the owner of the files send the links to each file and open them at least one time.
3. Make the owner of the files list the files in a sort of index file, i.e. a spreadsheet and search for the files in the spreadsheet instead of the Google Drive search.